# One-hot vector prediction always returns the same value

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, bigdata, conv-neural-network

My deep neural network returns the same output for every input. I tried (with no luck) different variations of:

- loss
- optimizer
- network topology / layers types
- number of epochs (1-100)

I have 3 outputs (one-hot) and for every input output they are like (it changes after every training):

> 4.701869785785675049e-01  4.793547391891479492e-01    2.381391078233718872e-01

This problem happens probably because of highly random nature of my training data (stock prediction).

The data set is also heavily shifted towards one of the answers (that's why I used `sample_weight` - calculated proportionally).

I think I can rule out overfitting (it happens even for 1 epoch and I have dropout layers).

One of the examples of my network:

```py
xs_conv = xs.reshape(xs.shape[0], xs.shape[1], 1)
model_conv = Sequential()
model_conv.add(Conv1D(128, 15, input_shape=(input_columns,1), activation='relu'))
model_conv.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model_conv.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_conv.add(Conv1D(64, 15, input_shape=(input_columns,1), activation='relu'))
model_conv.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model_conv.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_conv.add(Flatten())
model_conv.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model_conv.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_conv.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))

model_conv.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_conv.fit(xs_conv, ys, epochs=10, batch_size=16, sample_weight=sample_weight, validation_split=0.3, shuffle=True)
```

I would understand if the outputs were random, but what happens seems very peculiar. Any ideas?

Data: [computed.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m1OYIxVtcI0KsXyD-T8wquk75s7Blqpz)

Whole code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv1D, Dropout, MaxPooling1D, Flatten
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras import backend as K
import random

DATA_DIR = '../../Data/'
INPUT_DATA_FILE = DATA_DIR + 'computed.csv'

def get_y(row):
    profit = 0.010
    hot_one = [0,0,0]
    hot_one[0] = int(row.close_future_5 >= profit)
    hot_one[1] = int(row.close_future_5 <= -profit)
    hot_one[2] = int(row.close_future_5 < profit and row.close_future_10 > -profit)
    return hot_one

def rolling_window(window, arr):
    return [np.array(arr[i:i+window]).transpose().flatten().tolist() for i in range(0, len(arr))][0:-window+1]

def prepare_data(data, widnow, test_split):
    xs1 = data.iloc[:,1:26].as_matrix()
    ys1 = [get_y(row) for row in data.to_records()]
    xs = np.array(rolling_window(window, xs1)).tolist()
    ys = ys1[0:-window+1]
    zipped = list(zip(xs, ys))
    random.shuffle(zipped)

    train_size = int((1.0 - test_split) * len(data))

    xs, ys = zip(*zipped[0:train_size])
    xs_test, ys_test = zip(*zipped[train_size:])
    return np.array(xs), np.array(ys), np.array(xs_test), np.array(ys_test)

def get_sample_weight(y):
    if(y[0]): return ups_w
    elif(y[1]): return downs_w
    else: return flats_w

data = pd.read_csv(INPUT_DATA_FILE)
window = 30
test_split = .9

xs, ys, xs_test, ys_test = prepare_data(data, window, test_split)

ups_cnt = sum(y[0] for y in ys)
downs_cnt = sum(y[1] for y in ys)
flats_cnt = sum(y[0] == False and y[1] == False for y in ys)
total_cnt = ups_cnt + downs_cnt + flats_cnt
ups_w = total_cnt/ups_cnt
downs_w = total_cnt/downs_cnt
flats_w = total_cnt/flats_cnt

sample_weight = np.array([get_sample_weight(y) for y in ys])

_, input_columns = xs.shape


xs_conv = xs.reshape(xs.shape[0], xs.shape[1], 1)
model_conv = Sequential()
model_conv.add(Conv1D(128, 15, input_shape=(input_columns,1), activation='relu'))
model_conv.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model_conv.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_conv.add(Conv1D(64, 15, input_shape=(input_columns,1), activation='relu'))
model_conv.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
model_conv.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_conv.add(Flatten())
model_conv.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model_conv.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_conv.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))

model_conv.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_conv.fit(xs_conv, ys, epochs=1, batch_size=16, sample_weight=sample_weight, validation_split=0.3, shuffle=True)

xs_test_conv = xs_test.reshape(xs_test.shape[0], xs_test.shape[1], 1)
res = model_conv.predict(xs_test_conv)

plotdata = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['res_up','res_down','res_flat']), pd.DataFrame(ys_test, columns=['ys_up','ys_down','y_flat'])], axis = 1)

plotdata[['res_up', 'ys_up']][3000:3500].plot(figsize=(20,4))
plotdata[['res_down', 'ys_down']][3000:3500].plot(figsize=(20,4))
```

Comment: Can you provide the data to reproduce it?

Comment: @Maxim I attached the data as well as the whole code

Comment: Hmm... did you actually run it with this data? There is an `inf` at line 623.

Comment: Yes I have. And this turned out to be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run your model with the attached data and so far can say that the biggest problem is *lack of data cleaning*.

For instance, there's a `inf` value in `.csv` at line 623. After I've filtered them all out with

```
xs1 = xs1[np.isfinite(xs1).all(axis=1)]
```

... I collected some statistics over `xs`, namely min, max and mean. They turned out pretty remarkable:

```
-43.0049723138
32832.3333333    # !!!
0.213126234391
```

On average, the values are close to `0`, but some are 6 orders of magnitude higher. These particular rows definitely hurt the neural network, so you should either filter them as well or come up with a clever way to normalize the features.

But even with them, the model ended up with 71-79% validation accuracy. The result distribution is a bit skewed towards the 3rd class, but in general pretty diverse to name it *peculiar*: 19% for class 1, 7% for class 2, 73% for class 3. Example test output:

```
[[  1.93120316e-02   4.47684433e-04   9.97518778e-01]
 [  1.40607255e-02   2.45630667e-02   9.74113524e-01]
 [  3.07740629e-01   4.80920941e-01   2.28664145e-01]
 ..., 
 [  5.72797097e-02   9.45571139e-02   8.07634115e-01]
 [  1.05512664e-01   8.99530351e-02   6.70437515e-01]
 [  5.24505274e-03   1.46622911e-01   9.42657173e-01]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I only skimmed through the data and it seemed legit (beginner's mistake). The network worked fine on a different (and smaller) subsample. It didn't cross my mind, that the data could be corrupt on the larger sample and that it could lead to such a strange behavior of the network. Thanks again.